# Why does my build app fail when run outside of VS12 (i.e. when deployed)?

Tags: msbuild

I've written a c# program that builds *.csproj and *.vcxproj using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation. It works great on both project types if I compile and run it from inside Visual Studio 12. But if I run the exe directly (outside of Visual Studio) I get the example error message below. The error occurs only for vcx projects; c# projects continue to build just fine

**Question**: Why am I getting this error?  Why does my program work fine for both C# and vcx projects when run from within VS12, but fails, but only for vcx projects, when run outside of VS12?

Please don't chastise me for not using MSBuild.exe. My orders were to programmatically build C# and vcx projects using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.

**Code**:

```
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;
...

Project proj = new Project("MyCppProject.vcxproj");
proj.Build(logger);
```

**Runtime Error**:

```
Building MyCppProject
Project "MyCppProject.vcxproj" (default targets):
VCMessage: 
ERROR C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(518,5): Specified platform toolset (v110) is not installed or invalid. Please make sure that a supported PlatformToolset value is selected.
Done building project "MyCppProject" -- FAILED.
```

Comment: Thank you Juan for editing my question. It looks much better. Very kind of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to force the Visual Studio version as an environment variable prior to loading and building the project:

```
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;
...

Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("VisualStudioVersion", "11.0")
Project proj = new Project("MyCppProject.vcxproj");
proj.Build(logger);
```

Comment: This solves the problem! How do I give credit? Do I click on "Answer Your Question"?

Comment: Dunno, I never asked a question :)

Comment: Well I at least accepted your good answer and I thank you most sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio maintains platform tool sets list supported for the version of Visual studio you are currently running for example on my machine I have VS 2008, 2010 and 2012

[image]

Now suppose when I install Visual Studio 2013 which has a Platform Toolset version of V120. What happens, is that the project saves this in its corresponding XML files in the format (vcproj, vcxproj, vcxproj.filter.user files).

now this valus is not known to VS 2012 so it complains when opened in VS 2012.

Similarly for opening VS 2012 project in VS 2010, as in your case and so on.

## Solution:

To fix this issue, Open you solution file in notepad++. 
Make these 2 changes
1) Replace

> Format Version 12.00

with

> Format Version 11.00

2) Replace

> Visual Studio 2012

with

> Visual Studio 2010

Then open the file again in visual studio and rebuild solution.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh for taking time to respond. Unfortunately I don't know how to use your insights to fix the problem. What code changes do I need to make so that my app builds vcx projects when launched outside of VS12?

Comment: @oden, I have added the solution along with my previous answer.

Comment: Should I edit the solution file of 1) the targets I am trying to build, or 2) my application that does the building? If (1) then I am sunk because I am not allowed to change anything about the targets I am building. I could only do 2. Would you clarify which solution file I should edit? Thank you.